# OpenGL ES 2.0 drawing a circle of ticks/lines

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

What would be the best way to draw a circle of tick marks in OpenGL ES 2.0? such as you see in a speedometer.

I tried recalculating the cos and sin to get x and y for every vertex of every point, but it causes some wild flickering of the tick marks.

I tried a computationally cheaper way which only calculates the cos factor and tan factor once and uses multiplication and addition to build a circle, but it seems to be too inaccurate for a speedometer.

Any ideas?

Comment: There's no reason why using sin/cos would cause any flicker, you should be able to use that method without any problem. Maybe put up some code if you can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re-writing the cheaper method ( based on http://slabode.exofire.net/circle_draw.shtml ), I managed to get it to work. I'm still not sure why the sin and cos method caused flicker, unless calling sin and cos 200 times per frame refresh was too intense for the processor or something. Either way, calling cos and tan once per frame and only doing addition and multiplication 200 times seems to be working ok now.